# react-native run-android failed with error: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, react-native

I'm using windows 8.1. with 
`react-native-cli: 1.0.0` and
`react-native: 0.31.0`

After adding `react-native-maps` to the project, I ran command `react-native upgrade` and given **Y** to all questions.
Then linked deps with `rnpm link` as well as come changes to `MainApplication.java` file too.

Here are changes to `MainApplication.java`:

```
// Other imports ...
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

 private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
       return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
         new MainReactPackage(),
         new MapsPackage() // I have added this for react-native-maps
      );
    }
  };

 @Override
 public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
   return mReactNativeHost;
 }
}
```

Now I'm getting error when I run the command: `react-native run-android`

```
λ react-native run-android                                                                    
JS server already running.                                                                    
Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/platform-tools/adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:808
1                                                                                             
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug...      
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE                                                                      
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE                                                                 
:app:checkDebugManifest                                                                       
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE                                                               
:react-native-maps:compileLint                                                                
:react-native-maps:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE                                                 
:react-native-maps:preBuild UP-TO-DATE                                                        
:react-native-maps:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE                                                 
:react-native-maps:checkReleaseManifest                                                       
:react-native-maps:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE                                        
:react-native-maps:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE                                                   
:react-native-maps:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE                                           
:react-native-maps:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE                                         
:react-native-maps:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE                  
:react-native-maps:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE               
:react-native-maps:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE                    
:react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee0110Library UP-TO-DATE                       
:react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore0110Library UP-TO-DATE                       
:react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco0110Library UP-TO-DATE                       
:react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline0110Library UP-TO-DATE                
:react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase0110Library UP-TO-DATE            
:react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp30110Library UP-TO-DATE         
:react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0310Library UP-TO-DATE                   
:react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE                    
:react-native-maps:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE            
:react-native-maps:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE        
:react-native-maps:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE            
:react-native-maps:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE                        
:react-native-maps:prepareReleaseDependencies                                                 
:react-native-maps:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE                                              
:react-native-maps:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE                                      
:react-native-maps:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE                                      
:react-native-maps:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE                                           
:react-native-maps:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE                                              
:react-native-maps:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE                                        
:react-native-maps:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE                                        
:react-native-maps:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE                                           
:react-native-maps:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE                                          
:react-native-maps:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE                                         
:react-native-maps:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE                                          
:react-native-maps:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE                                           
:react-native-maps:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE                                     
:react-native-maps:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE                                       
:react-native-maps:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE                                       
:react-native-maps:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE                                               
:react-native-maps:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE                                               
:react-native-maps:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE                                           
:react-native-maps:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE                                          
:react-native-maps:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE                                      
:react-native-maps:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE                                         
:react-native-maps:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE                                                   
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE                                
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE                             
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE                                  
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee0110Library UP-TO-DATE                                     
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore0110Library UP-TO-DATE                                     
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco0110Library UP-TO-DATE                                     
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline0110Library UP-TO-DATE                              
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase0110Library UP-TO-DATE                          
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp30110Library UP-TO-DATE                       
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0310Library UP-TO-DATE                                 
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE                                  
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE                          
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE                      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE                          
:app:prepareNativeBaseDemoReactNativeMapsUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE                        
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE                                      
:app:prepareDebugDependencies                                                                 
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE                                                              
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE                                                      
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE                                                      
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE                                                           
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE                                                              
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE                                                        
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE                                                        
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE                                                           
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED                                                           
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE                                                          
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE                                                         
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE                                                          
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE                                                           
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE                                                     
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE                                                               
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE                                                           
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE                                                                   
:app:dexDebug                                                                                 
  Unknown source file : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:                                         
  Unknown source file : com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim;                                                                         
  Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)                                                                                             
  Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)  
  Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)  
  Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)      
  Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)           
  Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)                                                                                          
  Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)        
  Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)               
  Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245) 

  Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)       
:app:dexDebug FAILED                                                                          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                      

* What went wrong:                                                                            
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.                                                    
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2                                                                                     

* Try:                                                                                        
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.                                                                              

BUILD FAILED                                                                                  

Total time: 50.673 secs                                                                       
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.                    
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment:                                                  
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I have no idea about this error. Saw some questions similar to this but could not find the answer. I'm new to React-Native and Android development so I'm having hard time understanding this stuff.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This problem usually comes from gradle dependency in new components, i can see you have installed **react-native-maps**

you can solve it by cleaning the project.

1. In your React Native project:

> cd android/ && ./gradlew clean

2. go back and try run it again.

> cd .. && react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

to be more specific:

in your `MainApplication.java` file, change,

```
protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() { { <-----
```

on this

```
public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() { <-----
```

that got it building for me, at least

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that, the packager was running in the background from the previous build.

You might just try to close the packager server and start it with

```
react-native run-android
```

That was successful for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use these steps

> 1.) cd android
>
> 2.) gradle clean
>
> 3.) Now run the project.

This error occurs in my system whenever the emulator is updated.

Answer (score 0):

just run this from root of your project with cmd:

`cd android && gradlew clean`