# Build Failed React-Native Android: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'

Tags: java, android, gradle, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I am building my android app with react native using `react-native run-android`

However, after that I am receiving the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

After looking at multiple solutions and research, I ran a gradle clean and ran it again. Then I set up gradle daemon.

[react-native run-android failed with error: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127137/react-native-run-android-failed-with-error-execution-failed-for-task-appdexd)

Now the build time is faster; however, the error is still occurring.

**What is the reason for this problem? And how can this be resolved?**

Here is my MainApplication.java if needed

```
package com.wosyldelivery;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage()
      );
    }
    @Override
    protected String getJSBundleFile() {
      return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
      return mReactNativeHost;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there no answer for this?

Comment: run it with --stacktrace or -i to see what went wrong, the error you posted is not very helpful, plus gradle script would be nice with the task that fails, as it seems your exec task is doing something wrong and java can't execute it.

Comment: how to execute it with stacktrace?

Comment: gradle <your_task> --stacktrace

Comment: Looks like that's not working is why I was asking. Let me copy and paste it. 

Any idea?

Comment: Rohits-MacBook-Air:Wosyl-Delivery-1.0-master Spicycurryman$ gradle react-native run-android --stacktrace
-bash: gradle: command not found
Rohits-MacBook-Air:Wosyl-Delivery-1.0-master Spicycurryman$ react-native run-android --stacktrace
Scanning 591 folders for symlinks in /Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/Projects/Wosyl-Delivery-1.0-master/node_modules (14ms)

  error: unknown option `--stacktrace'

Rohits-MacBook-Air:Wosyl-Delivery-1.0-master Spicycurryman$

Comment: @InjuredThePatient you there?

Comment: Yes, I was off ;) hmm hard to read tbh, but can you disable daemon and clean it and try again ? additionally in gradle 3.5.x there is a deamon bug as far as im concerned not allowing you to disable it. would be great to see the script as well.